# Wishing a colleague a nice return to work after her vaccation

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice, word-order, standard-german

Is this sentence correct:

> Ich wünsche dir eine angenehme Rückkehr in die Arbeit.

Can one say this in German or would it make no sense?

Comment: The sentence is correct but it doesn't appear culturally appropriate. Assuming you are colleagues, I'd suggest something like "Willkommen zurück (zur Arbeit). Hattest Du einen schönen/erholsamen Urlaub?"

Comment: @Roland: I'm thinking the *Ich wünsche dir ...* version is grammatically correct, but too distant and emotionless for conversation between work colleagues. It makes me think of Data from "Star Trek: The Next Generation" or HAL from "2001".

Comment: @RDBury To me it sounds sarcastic.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment. Willkommen zurück zur Arbeit sounds friendlier and not as formal as "Ich wünsche dir eine angenehme Rückkehr in die Arbeit". I guess I can use the latter in more formal senarios?

Comment: Don't use it. At best, it sounds charming because you are trying and a beginner at the language. At worst, it sounds sarcastic. Also, in formal scenarios you need to switch to "Sie" instead of "Du".

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dein Satz ist korrekt und der Inhalt verständlich.

Zwei Alternativen, die ich im Berufsleben schon selbst gehört und benutzt habe:

Ich wünsche dir einen guten Start in den Arbeitsalltag.

Ich wünsche dir einen guten Start in die Arbeitswoche.

Comment: Willkommen! Wenn Sie können, bitte beantworten Sie die Frage in der Sprache, in der sie gestellt wurde. Das ist ein Brauch der Gemeinschaft.